# App synonyms/aliases (perhaps with Raycast)?

Tags: applications, spotlight, macos

Is there a way to create synonyms/custom names/aliases for Mac apps? For example, adding "Task manager" as an alternative to "Activity Monitor".

I use Raycast as a replacement for Spotlight. I'm guessing there's more flexibility/options using it related to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As alternative solution, one can make a shortcut with custom name, which open the wanted app. For example, this is a shortcut with name "Browser" to open Orion Browser:
[image: Screenshot of Shortcuts window.]

When you add this shortcut, you can see it in all launchers that support shortcuts search, such as Spotlight or Raycast.
[image: Screenshot of Raycast with created shortcut.]

On this way, you can create so many aliases as you want, it syncs to your Apple account and this works even on iOS and iPadOS if you have the same app on there.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to do this via the Extensions tab of Raycast: [image]